# How do I execute the code in express server only once?

Tags: node.js, express, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm developing a telegram chatbot using SendPulse API and Node.js that automatically replies after receiving a specific incoming message. But the issue I'm facing is that after receiving the incoming message through webhook it continuously sends the text message instead of just sending it once.

functions.js

```
var request = require('request');
require('dotenv').config("./env")

async function setAccessToken() {


    var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://api.sendpulse.com/oauth/access_token',
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "grant_type": "client_credentials",
            'client_id': process.env.client_id,
            'client_secret': process.env.client_secret,
        })

    };

    request(options, function (error, response) {

        if (error)
            throw new Error(error);
        body = JSON.parse(response.body)
        process.env.token = body.access_token

    });
}

const sendText = async (contact_id) => {

    var options = {

        'method': 'POST',
        'url': 'https://api.sendpulse.com/telegram/contacts/send',
        'headers': {

            'client_id': process.env.client_id,
            'client_secret': process.env.client_secret,
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "contact_id": contact_id,
            "message": {
                "type": "text",
                "text": "Hello from other side"
            }
        })

    };
    request(options, function (error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(response.body)

    });
}

module.exports = {
    sendText,
    setAccessToken
}
```

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require("express")

const TA = require("./functions")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.post("/telegram", async (req, res) => {

    if (req.body[0].contact.last_message === "Hello") {

        contact_id = req.body[0].contact.id
        await TA.sendText(contact_id)

    }

})

    nodeCron.schedule("*/1 * * * *", () => {
    console.log("Setting access token")
    TA.setAccessToken()


// res.sendStatus(200);

    //res.end()
    return res.status(200);

});

Port = process.env.PORT

app.listen(Port, () => console.log(`Listening to port ${Port}`))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Listening to port 3000
{"success":true,"data":true}
{"success":true,"data":true}
{"success":true,"data":true}
{"success":true,"data":true}
{"success":true,"data":true}
{"success":true,"data":true}
```

Note: I have to call setAccessToken as the authorization token expires every hour in SendPulse.

Answer (score 0):

Try after running send text add this to the end `res.status(200)`. I am guess it repeats itself because your not responding with anything.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply, I added res.status(200) but it doesn't work

Comment: Woops I mean with `return res.status(200)`

Comment: Yes, added that too, doesn't work

Comment: I wonder if it is `nodeCron` causing the issue. Also can't you call make it so in `POST /telegram` to check if token is expired or not if it is run `TA.setAccessToken()` otherwise continue sending message

Comment: Nah, node-cron isn't the issue

Comment: Yea. Sorry I don't know anymore.

Comment: If I use setAccessToken() function inside the POST /telegram . It gives {"message":"Unauthorized!","error_code":401}

Comment: No need to be sorry, I really appreciate your time.